# Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n = \ln(2) $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need some help in trying to solve this problem.

> We have the sequence defined as
> $$s_n = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n}$$
> for $n \geq 1$. We have to prove:
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n = \ln(2) $$

Now, I tried to rewrite the sequence as $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k}$. And now I am trying to find $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $a_n \leq s_n \leq b_n $. If the limit of both $a_n$ and $b_n$ tend to $\ln(2)$, then $s_n$ tends to $\ln(2)$ by Squeeze Theorem.

I am having problems to find $a_n$ and $b_n$, and I would like to receive help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get this problem? Is it from a class? If so, I'd recommend you share the particular class (calculus 2, intermediate real analysis, etc.) to ensure the hints/answers you receive use tools and results that are within your scope of knowledge.